# A unique can be used as index?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have this table:

```
// votes
+----+---------+---------+
| id | user_id | post_id |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | 12345   | 12      |
| 2  | 12345   | 13      |
| 3  | 52344   | 12      |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Also this is a part of my query:

```
EXISTS (select 1 from votes v where u.id = v.user_id and p.id = v.post_id)
```

To make my query more efficient, I have added a index group on `user_id` and `post_id`:

```
ALTER TABLE `votes` ADD INDEX `user_id,post_id` (`user_id,post_id`)
```

---

What's my question? I also want to prevent of duplicate vote from one user to one post. So I have to create a unique index on `user_id` and `post_id` too. Now I want to know, should I create another index? or just a unique index is enough and I should remove previous index?

Comment: UNIQUE index should be enough

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Ah ok thank you. So for this query: `... where col = :value`, if `col` be unique, then I shouldn't add a index on that anymore?

Comment: Unique constraints are implemented using unique indexes.  Another index on the same columns is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not  need two indexes serving similar purpose. Only one of them would be used during a `select` operation, and both will have to be modified on `insert, update` and `delete`. These are unnecessary overheads. Go with the unique index, since it serves both the purposes. A range scan is almost guaranteed when using a unique indexed columns in a `where` clause.

**EDIT :**

The term for index does not matter. When you are creating an index, a B- tree structure is created, selecting a convenient root node, and rearranging column values. If all entries in the given column are going to be unique, normal index would also be of the same size as unique index, and would give same performance as unique index.

Primary index is also a unique index, with the exception that it would not allow null values.Null values are permitted in a unique index.

Comment: *"You do not need two indexes serving similar purpose."* A normal index and a unique index are for two separated purpose. normal index increases the speed of searching and unique index avoid of duplicate rows. All I want to know, a unique index can also acts as a normal index too?

Answer (score 1):

if you're trying to prevent multiple votes from the same `user_id` to the same `post_id`, then why don't you use a [`UNIQUE` constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)?

```
ALTER TABLE votes
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_votes UNIQUE (user_id,post_id)
```

with regards to whether you should remove your index, you should review [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) concepts for query plan execution paths and performance. I suspect it will be better to keep them, but it will require testing.

Comment: I have a primary key on my table, `id` is primary, and I read somewhere a table can accept just one primary column. beside, why not unique?

Comment: in this case, I think it makes sense to change primary keys. you might even consider removing the `id` column entirely if you're not referencing it elsewhere. whatever you decide, using all 3 in a composite will not work, since this would allow multiple votes, i.e. don't do `PRIMARY KEY (id,user_id,post_id)`

Comment: actually, updated my answer to simply use a unique constraint which will probably be more flexible for you

Comment: I suspect it will be better to keep them, but you will need to test by analyzing the alternate paths for the [Query Execution Plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) with and without the indexes

Comment: Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE votes`.  If you see more than one `PRIMARY KEY` / `UNIQUE` / `INDEX` / `KEY` for `(user_id,post_id)`, then you have redundancy, and you 'should' get rid of the lesser one(s).

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL:
A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key.
A `UNIQUE` key is an `INDEX`.
"index" and "key" are synonyms.

Comment: Furthermore, there is probably no use for `id`.  Once you have a `UNIQUE` key, it is worth considering whether it should be the `PRIMARY KEY`.  If this is your entire table (3 columns), I would get rid of `id` and promote `(user_id,post_id)` to `PRIMARY KEY`.